# XSS attack - Sanitizing input vs Rejection

Tags: xss

Lately, have become interested in XSS and its prevention methods. 
Most of the XSS prevention techniques focus on sanitizing the input for invalid characters and using them. This raises a question:

When it is obvious that the purpose is indeed an XSS attack why are we trying to strip the invalid characters and then going ahead with using the input instead of directly rejecting the input as such and sending the usage to an error page?

Am sure that everyone would have thought of this approach but somehow focus is on input validation,filtering and reusing instead of rejection. Why? What am I missing here?

Comment: There is more to XSS than "invalid characters".

Comment: @Diodeus:Can you please elaborate? In my case, I expect only a single parameter in my application and the requirement is that this will be alphanumeric and devoid of any special characters. So if I find any special characters,html tags I was planning to directly send the user to an errorPage without further processing or storing. Will this not take care of XSS?

Comment: XSS = cross-site-scripting. This is where you allow third-party content on your page. This third-party content then hijacks your page. Sterilizing inputs and XSS are two completely different topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule I use is, I use input validation to make sure data is valid according to the domain. If I expect a number and get a string of letters, I reject it. If however I have a text field that can include anything (like a comment on stack overflow), input validation and rejection is virtually impossible. So now I need to sanitize/output encode.

Answer (score 1):

because mostly when input is wrong you already show an error page

for instance

```
page.php?id=a33

"select * from table where id = ".((Int)$_GET['id']);
```

the "num rows" value will be 0 because you are searching for:

```
"select * from table where id = 0";
```

in plus in some cases any string, even if corrupted can be useful for what the program is going to do, for instance a search string...

and again, don't do nothing can be frustrating for the user. better if sanitize and show a warning if some data were lost

Comment: I agree that if input is wrong we will be showing an error page to the user. But, XSS comes into picture when we redisplay the unsanitized input as such to the user. So if we are not going to redisplay it to the user, then why should we bother sanitizing it? Please note that my assumption is that if you expect an input in a certain format but the input contains malicious code, it is safe to assume that it is a hijacker.

Comment: not, because on some systems, on some browsers, on some other galaxies you can get some false positives, due to client's bad configuration or server's bad configuration. in general you are right. but better don't give tips to hijackers, IMHO... i mean writing "you have entered the null byte so the request will be skipped" helps the hijacker to exclude all the null byte based attacks... so, do it silently.